# Issue with POST using React

Tags: reactjs, post

Hello I am newer at react but I am getting an error when I am trying to POST and I think that it is my changeHandler Wondering if someone can see something that I don't.

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


  class Form extends Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        appointment:{
            customer_first_name: "",
            customer_last_name: "",
            date: "",
            email: "",
            notes: "",
            phone: "",
            time: ""
        }
    }
}

changeHandler = e => {
    var appointment = { ...this.state.appointment };
    appointment.[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({appointment})
}

submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state)
    axios
        .post('test/api', this.state.appointment)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

Comment: What error are you getting. Can you post a little bit more?

Comment: At appoint.[e.target.name] it is saying identifier expected.

Comment: Try this instead: 
changeHandler = e => {
    var appointment = { ...this.state.appointment, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
    this.setState({appointment})
}

Comment: Oh, by the way, you cannot do: appointment.[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
If you are using the bracket notation, then you must use: appointment[e.target.name] = e.target.value; Note that there is no dot between appointment and the "[".

Comment: I have responded as a question. If it solves your problem, please mark it accordingly.

Comment: The change handler response at the bottom resolved the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntactical error in your `changeHandler`. If you are using the bracket notation, then you do not use a dot:

```js
// wrong
appointment.[e.target.name] = e.target.value;

// right
appointment[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
```

Besides, you can combine the deconstruction and assignment operation as follows:

```js
changeHandler = e => {
    var appointment = { ...this.state.appointment, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
    this.setState({appointment})
}
```

Note that because the assignment comes after the deconstruction, if a variable with the same name already exists, it is overwritten by the new value as set by `[e.target.name]: e.target.value`.